# What is the meaning of a DNS MX record '.'

Tags: dns

Found a domain with MX record ".". What does that mean exactly (e.g., theplug.org)?

```
IN  MX  3402    . 0
```

- Is MX the same as the domain?
- Means the dot a invalid MX?
- Is it a catch-all mail address?
- Or totally different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a so-called "Null MX" record, defined by [RFC 7505](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7505) in 2015. It explains, that this was introduced to bring

> a simple mechanism by which a domain can indicate that it does not
> accept email.

Further discussion on this topic here on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/714052/why-is-rfc-7505-null-mx-necessary).